# Find numbers $a, b, c$ given that $a+b+c=12$, $a^2+b^2+c^2=50$, and $a^3+b^3+c^3=168$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, systems-of-equations, symmetric-polynomials

> Let $a+b+c=12$, $a^2+b^2+c^2=50$, and $a^3+b^3+c^3=168$. Find $a,b,c$

Suppose $a, b, c$ are roots of $P(x)$.

$$P(x) = k(x - a)(x - b)(x - c)$$

But then I get $(k = 1)$

$$P(x) = x^3 - 12x^2 + x(ab + ac + bc) - abc$$

Cant go further...

Comment: Do you want integral solution ?

Comment: If yes then check the number $168$..

Comment: Similar questions: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27394/three-variable-system-of-simultaneous-equations/ or http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/403454/is-there-a-simpler-approach-to-these-system-of-equations (You could probably find more questions like this.)

Comment: The point is whether you can express $a^2+b^2+c^2$ and $a^3+b^3+c^3$ using $a+b+c$, $ab+ac+bc$ and $abc$. See [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities) at Wikipedia.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray}ab+bc+ca=\frac{1}{2}((a+b+c)^2-(a^2+b^2+c^2))=47\end{eqnarray}
\begin{align*}a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc&=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-(ab+bc+ca))\\ abc&=44\end{align*}
So $a, b, c$ are roots of the polynomial $x^3-12x^2+47x-44=0$.

Comment: $12\cdot 12-50=144-50=94$ and $94/2=47$

Comment: $\frac{168+3\cdot 12\cdot 47-12^3}{3}=44$

Answer (score 1):

$$a^2+b^2+c^2=(a+b+c)^2-2(ab+ac+bc)$$

So $ab+ac+bc=\frac{(a+b+c)^2-(a^2+b^2+c^2)}{2}=47$

Similarly

$$a^3+b^3+c^3=(a+b+c)^3+3abc-3(a+b+c)(ab+ac+bc)$$

So $abc=\frac{a^3+b^3+c^3+3(a+b+c)(ab+ac+bc)-(a+b+c)^3}{3}=44$
And $a,b,c$ are solutions of the cubic

$$X^3-12X^2+47X-44=0$$

No simple solution except Cardan formulaes